Is there a name for this aspect of Christian moral epistemology?
I would like to know more about the idea that "the law is written on our hearts", but I'm not sure what this idea is called within Christian doctrine or within the tradition of Western philosophy more broadly. Any pointers?

The name is epistemic sentimentalism and it is not specifically Christian:"Epistemic sentimentalists hold that (some) emotions are sources of moral knowledge or at least justification. Many of them believe the stronger claim that emotional experiences are necessary for coming to know basic moral truths..." Many Christians combine it with the divine command theory "that morality is somehow dependent upon God, and that moral obligation consists in obedience to God’s commands."

So then you just have to decide who was holding the pen: God or evolution? Both get the job done. Any relation to Virtue Ethics though?

If you want to ask about Christian doctrine specifically, I'd suggest asking on the Christianity Stack Exchange site. Questions about philosophy more broadly are probably appropriate here.

The philosophical name for this notion "the law is written in their hearts" is "natural law", see: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/natural-law-ethics/#NatLawDivPro
There is no harm in asking this question here, since (1) Western philosophy since late Roman times has been deeply colored by the merger of Christianity with Greek philosophy and (2) Christian and Islamic religion has expressed its own experiences - both in their sacred books and in the apologetic traditions - using Greek philosophical language (not always digested very well).

@Conifold Actually, you are assuming that by "heart" is meant "feelings."  In fact, the heart was regarded as a source of thought.  As witness "learn by heart."

@Mary Emotions, as understood by sentimentalists, are hardly devoid of thought, they could not be sources of knowledge and justification otherwise. The 'heart' was the literal seat of mind generally in ancient accounts, and in Christian and Islamic morality contexts it was typically a metaphorical stand-in for conscience or "moral sense", see SEP.

@Conifold  Then your quote on their views is misleading, given the common view.  Also, you still have to show that emotions are involved at all.

This is referring to conscience.  I think philosophy in general uses the same term, at least for the basic idea.  The phrase "law written in their hearts" comes from Romans 2:14-16:

For when the Gentiles, which have not the law, do by nature the things contained in the law, these, having not the law, are a law unto themselves: which shew the work of the law written in their hearts, their conscience also bearing witness, and their thoughts the mean while accusing or else excusing one another;) in the day when God shall judge the secrets of men by Jesus Christ according to my gospel.

In Christianity specifically, the conscience "bears witness" to this law, indicating that the law itself is written more deeply than even the conscience, in the very "heart."  You might say that the conscience is what makes this law clear to us.

Widely supported in Hinduism as well, see the Bhagavad Gita. (I had to beat @Rushi to the punch)

If this "law" is supposed to "objective" (as Christians commonly claim), that creates a whole bunch of problems given individuals and entire societies across history and in the modern day having vastly different moral views and different consciences. That's strong evidence against the idea that we have an unchanging law "written onto our hearts". Christians try to explain that away by saying we've been corrupted by "sin" or whatever, but if you claim we have the "law", but some people don't because "sin", and we seem to have no (objective) way to tell that apart, then it's a pointless claim.

@NotThatGuy In Christianity, the Bible affirms that the conscience can be "seared with a hot iron" (I Timothy 4:2), but that implies they once were aware of this universal law.  And people can also deny what their conscience says.  But the Bible isn't saying here that we can objectively prove that this law is written on each heart; it's a truth we as Christians take on faith in God's word.

@PeterRankin "the Bible isn't saying here that we can objectively prove this" - yeah, it's just making a claim we have no evidence to support, and that claim is contrary to the evidence, and it tries to "fix" that with more unsupported claims, and you end up with something entirely indistinguishable from those claims not being true. There is a lot of that going on in Christianity. Also, you could post-hoc rationalise your way into explaining why 1 or 2 people have bad morals, but entire societies across thousands of years? Saying all those people were denying their conscience would be absurd.

@NotThatGuy - To be fair, any substantive, important difference between two moral codes that both claim to be "reasonable" and "universal" (applicable to all humans) seems problematic to both systems. It doesn't matter imo whether those codes are embedded in a religious tradition or not. But I think that "natural law" is an attempt to explain the reverse observation -- that basic parts of moral codes are found in very different religions/cultural traditions, so instead of closing off the dialogue, it tries to open it -- unfortunately mainly used for proselytizing instead of listening...

@mudskipper Christianity makes the claim of a universal/objective moral law, that everyone already knows. I'll grant that moral disagreement is problematic for every moral system or worldview that makes a similar claim, but I'm not sure how that helps your case. I don't hold to such a system or worldview, and I'm fine with throwing all systems that do into the trash. (Evolution explains why "basic parts of moral codes" are found all over, even among animals, it doesn't have issues with that not being universal, and it's exceedingly well-supported by evidence, but that's not a moral system)

@NotThatGuy - Note I'm only playing devil's (I'm sorry, the angel's!) advocate here.

@ScottRowe Could you please give a specific reference (Book, verse) about the role of conscience in the Bhagavadgita? Thanks.

@NotThatGuy I don't think it's farfetched to say entire cultures as a whole deny parts of their consciences.  I heard of a study where 12 people in a room were asked which line was shorter.  The answer was pretty clear, but 11 were told ahead of time to say the wrong answer.  As they answered one by one, at first the 12th guy looked surprised, then disturbed, but then by his turn, with confidence he gave the wrong answer with the rest!

@JoWehler I'm not Scott! But see BG 3.36-43.

So the problem is the person who told the majority to lie. "Doctor, it hurts when I do this." - "Well, don't do that!"

@gs Which Sanskrit term in BG 3.36-43 do you consider to denote conscience?

@JoWehler I know absolutely nothing about translating ancient Sanskrit, just what I get from the context of the English translation done by others, but I think ātmanā/higher self/soul has that connotation as the innermost seat of moral self-knowing, and the same connotation as Paul's 'the heart'.

@JoWehler if you meant conscience as a sort of divine homunculus, like it's sometimes thought of, as opposed to the soul's capacity for moral self-knowing, I don't think you find that there. But I don't think you can find that in St. Paul or elsewhere in the Bible or Christian tradition, either.

@PeterRankin That's in no way analogous. You just presented an example where over 90% of people already held one position, and the remaining less-than-10% was swayed by peer pressure. You're trying to use this as evidence that you can get from close to 0% to over 90% - peer pressure can't convince people of a position almost no-one holds. And you're comparing saying a line is longer with people oppressing, abusing, torturing and murdering others. And you're comparing how people behave in one isolated situation with how they behave every day for millennia. Not similar.

@PeterRankin If you want an actual analogous situation, one could consider that children of science-denying bigots, raised in a science-denying bigoted society, are more likely to be science-denying bigots themselves. But this isn't evidence for your position, it's evidence against it. This is much better explained by our (sincere) sense of right and wrong being largely defined by our parents and our environment. Your position is just an unjustified assertion contrary to reality - you're asserting there's something inside these people despite every piece of evidence being contrary to that.
